# Featured Image problem with resizing

Tags: images

I want include function to resize featured image to 80x80, im add this code in my function.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(80, 80);
```

But is not work very good, images is not resized, looks like scaled to 80x65 or something..
i need exactly 80x80 on every images uploaded...

Comment: Did you upload images after adding these lines or before it?

Comment: Im edit function.php and after that im try upload images

Comment: To apply changed thumbnail sizes to already uploaded images you have to regenerate the thumbnails, for example with the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to pass the third `$crop` parameter to `set_post_thumbnail_size`. In other words...

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(80, 80, true);
```

That third parameter enables a "hard-crop" mode. [From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size):

> Set the default Post Thumbnail size by cropping the image (either from
>   the sides, or from the top and bottom):

Without that argument, or with it set to `false`, you get a resize without distortion-- ie. as close as possible to your dimensions. Also from the Codex:

> Set the default Post Thumbnail size by resizing the image
>   proportionally (that is, without distorting it):

Answer (score 0):

You too, can add a Thumbnail size using add_image_size().

```
<?php add_image_size( 'email', 300, 200, true ); ?>
```

Then you can user from your theme:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail('email');
}
?>
```